# Decay rate of absolutely continuous square integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, partial-differential-equations

I have an absolutely continuous function $f\in L^2(0,\infty)$ and $f'\in L^2(0,\infty)$. This implies that $f(t)\to 0$ for $t\to \infty$. (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1472757/410611))

1. Can one say anything on the rate of convergence?
2. More specific can I say that $t^\frac{1}{2} f(t)\to 0$ for $t\to \infty$?
3. What would be a reasonable additional assumption (except monotony, which is not the case. Otherwise [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3960985) would do the trick) in order to get some estimates on the rate of convergence? Or are there some references that do something similar. This comes from a PDE problem so this function might fulfill these additional assumptions but right now I am not sure what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately, the decay rate can be arbitrarily bad.**

Take $\phi \in C^\infty_c((-1,1);[0,1])$ a smooth compactly supported bump function, say with $\phi(0) = 1$. Then put
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \phi(x-x_n)
$$
for some sequence $x_n \to + \infty$. Then $f, f' \in L^2$ because the sum of the $n^{-2}$ converges. But $f(x_n) = n^{-2}$ and you could choose $x_n$ to go very very fast to infinity. For example, with $x_n = n^6$, you prove that $t^{\frac 12}f(t)$ does not tend to $0$. And you could use $x_n = e^n$ or $e^{e^n}$ or even faster. The argument actually contradicts any kind of quantitative decay.